# Is there a way to view access logs for EC2 load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

The title pretty much sums it up. Is there a way to view the access logs for my EC2 load balancer? The access logs on my E2 instance all show traffic coming from the load balancer, which isn't very helpful. I am using VPC, this is on my public subnet, so maybe the IP I am seeing is from my NAT.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to view access logs for EC2 load balancer. If you want to see the client IPs you can consult the "X-Forwarded-For" header.